# Sort arrangement in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting an array from a database (in descending order) and I paint them on the front in a table and in a graph as shown in the image:

[image]

but in the part of the graph I want to sort in ascending order and I do the following:

```
export class PruebasComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any[];
  dataSource: PeriodicElement[] = [];
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[];
    .......
 ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;


    this.datos.getDesktopLimit().subscribe(
      res => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.data = [res];
        this.dataSource = this.data[0]; //aqui almaceno el arreglo y lo paso al componente html
        this.barChartData = true;
        this.getFilter(this.dataSource); // ejecuto la funcion getFilter()
      }
    )
  }
```

with a `sort` I sort it in ascending order to pass it to the graph

```
  getFilter(data) {
    console.log(data);

     data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id); //ordenar de forma ascendente para la grafica

    for (let entry of data) {
      this.date.push(moment(entry.created).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'))
      this.time.push(entry.total_load_time * 0.001)
    }

    this.lineChartData =  [{ data: this.time, label: 'Time Render' }];
    this.lineChartLabels = this.date;
    this.loading = false
  }
```

**It effectively orders me but the table is also sorted in ascending order**

[image]

Comment: Stackoverflow.com is for English questions ;)
If you want to ask a question in Spanish, visit https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I was in the Spanish section

Comment: So you only want to sort the data in the graph? You seem to be doing everything by reference, so you’ll need to make a copy of the data (a new instance) for the graph data so you can change it independently..

Answer (score 0):

The following line do nothing;

```
data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```

You have to assign the value from it:

```
sortedDataForGraph : any[];


...


sortedDataForGraph = data.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
```